# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 27, saw 367

Tags: python, pandas

plz...I'm tired, help me to figure out

## **This is my code**

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/Ionosphere.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(url)
df.head()
```

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 27, saw 367

Comment: This is fetching an HTML page and parsing it as CSV. You need to change this URL to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Ionosphere.csv`

Answer (score 1):

You need to **convert** your `URL` so that it contains the `raw.githubusercontent.com` domain. The `raw.githubusercontent.com` domain is used to serve unprocessed versions of files stored in GitHub repositories. If you browse to a file on GitHub and then click the Raw link, that's where you'll go. This is what it would look like in your code:

```
import pandas as pd
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Ionosphere.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(url)
```

`df.head()` returns:

```
   V1  V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10      V11      V12  ...      V24      V25      V26      V27      V28      V29      V30      V31      V32      V33      V34  Class
0   1   0  0.99539 -0.05889  0.85243  0.02306  0.83398 -0.37708  1.00000  0.03760  0.85243 -0.17755  ... -0.47357  0.56811 -0.51171  0.41078 -0.46168  0.21266 -0.34090  0.42267 -0.54487  0.18641 -0.45300      1
1   1   0  1.00000 -0.18829  0.93035 -0.36156 -0.10868 -0.93597  1.00000 -0.04549  0.50874 -0.67743  ... -0.35734 -0.20332 -0.26569 -0.20468 -0.18401 -0.19040 -0.11593 -0.16626 -0.06288 -0.13738 -0.02447      0
2   1   0  1.00000 -0.03365  1.00000  0.00485  1.00000 -0.12062  0.88965  0.01198  0.73082  0.05346  ... -0.12062  0.57528 -0.40220  0.58984 -0.22145  0.43100 -0.17365  0.60436 -0.24180  0.56045 -0.38238      1
3   1   0  1.00000 -0.45161  1.00000  1.00000  0.71216 -1.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  ...  0.00000  1.00000  0.90695  0.51613  1.00000  1.00000 -0.20099  0.25682  1.00000 -0.32382  1.00000      0
4   1   0  1.00000 -0.02401  0.94140  0.06531  0.92106 -0.23255  0.77152 -0.16399  0.52798 -0.20275  ... -0.52879  0.03286 -0.65158  0.13290 -0.53206  0.02431 -0.62197 -0.05707 -0.59573 -0.04608 -0.65697      1

[5 rows x 35 columns]
```